# iPhone Dev - Where is RootViewController instantiated in a Navigation-based application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I can't seem to find where it's actually instantiated. I looked in the myProjAppDelegate.m and saw this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

But it says that the window's rootViewController property is really just a UIViewController, not a UITableViewController, which is what the RootViewController.m class is a subclass of. I wrote a custom method in my RootViewController.m and tried to call it on self.navigationController in myProjAppDelegate.m and got a SIGABRT, so it seems like this is not it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not visible in code. Your MainWindow.xib contains a Window and a Navigation Controller which are connected via outlets to your AppDelegate. 
Both the Window and the Navigation Controller get instantiated when the application loads the .xib files.
Inside the Window (in the MainWindow.xib) is a RootViewController, that is the RootViewController you are talking about.

Regarding the class, UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController.

Comment: They are instantiated when application loads that .xib file, not at compilation level, as I know...

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why I can't call my custom method that I wrote inside RootViewController.m on the Window's rootViewController property then. Any ideas?

Comment: In order to access your RootViewController from your appDelegate you can say RootViewController *r = (RootViewController *)self.navigationController.topViewController;